# Amazon Cognito Delete account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have Amazon Cognito user pool with few users added in it. I have added trigger to invoke my Lambda function after Post confirmation. Do we have any trigger in Cognito to invoke the Lambda function after "User Signout" and "Delete User". I did not see any trigger in Cognito.

How the lambda function can be invoked automatically after User signout and Delete user. Kindly throw some light on this.

Comment: There isn’t any trigger in cognito. But you should be able to call your own lambda from your client when you sign out.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Can't be done

It can't be done automatically because unlike Sign-in/Sign-ups which create an event, there is no logout event per se. Even the [LOGOUT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) endpoint just clears the existing session. Normally, in such cases we could have done some workaround using Cloudtrail but there is no API for sign out (unless you count [GlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html)) and even then Cognito does not log user level APIs.