# Integrate cognito and dynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

Basically this is the scenario i use a aws cognito service as the id server of a aplicattion and i have some dynamo tables that save some of those users.

I need to delete a user on those dynamoDB tables when i delete the same user on a cognito pool

this is the work flow.

1. User is deleted on cognito.
2. Lambda or any apropriate service listen to the event trigger.
3. Lambda or any apropriate service delete user from the dynamoDB tables.

i was reading the docs from aws and other peoples questions on stackoverflow, [Triggering a Lambda function upon deleting a user on AWS Cognito User Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876341/triggering-a-lambda-function-upon-deleting-a-user-on-aws-cognito-user-pool), [Amazon Cognito Delete account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313165/amazon-cognito-delete-account) and  i realized that cognito dont have a specific trigger for delete event.

How can i achieve that described workflow ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any limitations on your AWS services? You can't do this out-of-box with cognito pools.

Comment: thanks for your reply @SamRastovich, no i dont have any limitations how can i do this using cognito pools? im a newbie  on the aws universe

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not supported out-of-the-box by Amazon Cognito. You will have to write your own solution with a combination of other Amazon services.

There are a lot of ways to implement this, but one thing we've done in our applications:

First, create your own API endpoint such as: **DELETE /user**. You can do it with [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/)

Second, connect your API endpoint to a Lambda function, or host your code elsewhere, but you need to call the Cognito user pool API with your code and delete it like that. Here is a snippet of how that can be done in NodeJS

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'access key id',
  secretAccessKey: 'secret access key',
  region: 'region',
});
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

await cognito.adminDeleteUser({
  UserPoolId: 'pool id',
  Username: 'username',
}).promise();
```

(For the full answer on how to delete a user with code, check this [stack overflow question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020630/how-to-delete-the-cognito-user-in-node-js))

Comment: Thank you , i will try to use this approach